# Combining Two Queries in SQL

Tags: sql

Basically I need to combine the result of these two queries where the PSROLEUSER is equal in both tables.  How would I do this?

```
select PSROLEUSER from sysadm.PSROLEUSER where ROLENAME = 'NCC_Manag';
select PSROLEUSER from sysadm.PSROLEUSER where ROLENAME = 'HRM-Content Amin';
```

Comment: What database system you're using?

Comment: There is only one table in your example, not two.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an approach that puts all the logic in the `having` clause:

```
select PSROLEUSER
from sysadm.PSROLEUSER 
group by PSROLEUSER
having sum(case when ROLENAME = 'NCC_Manag' then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and
       sum(case when ROLENAME = 'HRM-Content Amin' then 1 else 0 end) > 0;
```

I like this approach because it is quite general.  For instance, if you wanted all`'NCC_Manag'` that are *not* `'HRM_Content Amin'`, you would do:

```
select PSROLEUSER
from sysadm.PSROLEUSER 
group by PSROLEUSER
having sum(case when ROLENAME = 'NCC_Manag' then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and
       sum(case when ROLENAME = 'HRM-Content Amin' then 1 else 0 end) = 0;
```

Answer (score 2):

The query below assumes that `ROLENAME` is unique for every `PSROLEUSER`.

```
SELECT  PSROLEUSER 
FROM    sysadm.PSROLEUSER 
WHERE   ROLENAME IN ('NCC_Manag', 'HRM-Content Amin')
GROUP   BY PSROLEUSER
HAVING  COUNT(*) = 2
```

- [SQL of Relational Division](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/divided-we-stand-the-sql-of-relational-division/)

Comment: No that would not work because IN is basically OR.  I need the PSROLEUSER to basically have NCC_Manag AND HRM-Content Admin

Answer (score 1):

Another way:

```
select X.PSROLEUSER from
(select PSROLEUSER from sysadm.PSROLEUSER where ROLENAME = 'NCC_Manag') X inner join 
(select PSROLEUSER from sysadm.PSROLEUSER where ROLENAME = 'HRM-Content Amin') Y
on X.PSROLEUSER = Y.PSROLEUSER
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select PSROLEUSER from sysadm.PSROLEUSER where ROLENAME in('NCC_Manag','HRM-Content Amin')
```

Try this code

Answer (score 0):

```
select PSROLEUSER from sysadm.PSROLEUSER where ROLENAME = 'NCC_Manag'
UNION
select PSROLEUSER from sysadm.PSROLEUSER where ROLENAME = 'HRM-Content Amin'
```

Assuming they return the same schema, just union them.

Answer (score 0):

Also you can use another version with EXISTS operator.

```
SELECT t1.PSROLEUSER
FROM sysadm.PSROLEUSER t1
WHERE t1.ROLENAME = 'NCC_Manag'
  AND EXISTS (
              SELECT 1
              FROM sysadm.PSROLEUSER t2
              WHERE t2.ROLENAME = 'HRM-Content Amin'
                AND t1.PSROLEUSER = t2.PSROLEUSER
              )
```

See demo on [`SQLFiddle`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/44e3e/3)

Answer (score 0):

```
select distinct psroleuser from psroleuser where rolename = 'NCC_Manag'
and psroleuser in 
(select psroleuser from psroleuser where rolename = 'HRM-Content Amin')
```